# how to become root then execute script remote

Tags: ansible

I met issue run remote script by ansible. I need run the remote script after `become root (run sudo su -)`.

ansible can't take me to root by `become_method` in YML? is any config file issue or playbook command issue here ?

```
[root@automation ansible]#  ansible-playbook YML/disk_scan.yml -i hosts
SSH password:

PLAY [test] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [copy] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [test101.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Missing sudo password"}
```

```
- hosts: test
#  serial: 5
  become: yes   
  become_method: sudo   
  become_user: root   
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

    - copy:
        src: /etc/ansible/scripts/Raid_check.py
        dest: /tmp/



    - name: Run Raid Check
      command: python /tmp/Raid_check.py
      register: command_output
    - debug: msg="{{ command_output.stdout }}"
```

```
[defaults]
inventory       = /etc/ansible/hosts
host_key_checking = false
remote_tmp     = $HOME/.ansible/tmp
pattern        = *
forks          = 10
poll_interval  = 15
ask_pass=True
sudo_user      = root
user           = test
remote_user = test
transport      = smart
#module_lang    = C
gathering = smart
fact_caching = redis
#sudo_exe = sudo
timeout = 15
ansible_managed = Ansible managed: {file} modified on %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S by {uid} on {host}
action_plugins     = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/action_plugins
callback_plugins   = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/callback_plugins
connection_plugins = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/connection_plugins
lookup_plugins     = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/lookup_plugins
vars_plugins       = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/vars_plugins
filter_plugins     = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/filter_plugins
deprecation_warnings=False
fact_caching = memory
[paramiko_connection]
[ssh_connection]
[accelerate]
accelerate_port = 5099
accelerate_timeout = 30
accelerate_connect_timeout = 5.0
accelerate_daemon_timeout = 30
```

```
fatal: [test101.com]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 12726\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 1\r\nShared connection to test101.com closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the become password when you run the cli command.

Try `ansible-playbook YML/disk_scan.yml -i hosts -K`. Note, the `-K` is shorthand to prompt for super user password.

Comment: Even by using the -K, I can see the remote script not running by root. means it not become root to run script.

Comment: @The_flash is there any error ? Also please update the question with the command executed using debug mode append `-vvvv` with the ansible command.